# Me sale error cuando falta una columna en una tabla PANDAS con "loc[:,order]"

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente orden de las columnas

```
order=['COD','ARTICULO','COLOR','S','M','L','XL','XXL','2']
dff=dff.loc[:,order]
```

EL problema que tengo es que cuando no hay XXL o cualquiera de esas me arroja error y se cierra el formulario y me sale el siguiente error.

```
"Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['XXL', '2'], dtype='object').
```

O sea que solo funciona cuando hay todas esas columnas mencionadas, pero en mi tabla las cantidad de columnas son variables ¿Cómo podría solucionar este impase?

Comment: Pues a lo mejor puedes usar `.iloc[]` en vez de `.loc[]`, pues te permite seleccionar columnas por sus índices en vez de por sus nombres. En todo caso el problema no está muy bien definido ¿no? Si quieres sacar ciertas columnas pero esas columnas no están ¿qué esperas que ocurra?

Comment: @abulafa En el caso de por ejemplo manejar una tabla con los stocks de unas ropas en almacén. Pueden haber todas las tallas mencionadas en 'order'(S, M, L, XL, XXL), pero también podría suceder que solo haya la talla M. En ese caso me sale el error que menciono porque el sistema me exige que hayan todas las tallas. El mensaje error me sugiere agregar "or []" para los valores vacíos (Me imagino) pero no sé donde ponerlo.

Comment: @johnnypk quizá entonces lo que deberías hacer es comprobar que tienes las columnas necesarias y crear vacías las faltantes